# I'm out of ideas how to get my usb drive working again.No solutions on the internet worked

Tags: linux, windows, usb, gparted, filesystem-corruption

The device is not visible under the section *Mount Devices* in Parted Magic, nor in my mini-install of Windows XP.

I've tried several things to fix the 16GB flash drive, which is a *Kingston Data Traveler 2.0*, like formatting, assigning disk letters, re-installing drivers (while it was still visible) and `fdisk -l` in Parted Magic.

Still, `lsusb` does show it.

```
root@PartedMagic:~# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0951:1665 Kingston Technology
```

I think I've also tried to use all the options available  in *Disk Shredder* in Parted Magic, but now it says **`No drives have been detected`**.

*Gparted* says `input output error`, and I have to <kbd>Ignore</kbd> or <kbd>Retry</kbd> forever, and then it says couldn't open dev/sda because no such file or directory exists, as well as `An error occured while creating partition table` (it says I have to make one and it is showing the flash drive as unallocated).

Right after the failed attempt, *Gparted* stops seeing it anymore, and so does `lsusb` also. However, after plugging the USB flash drive into the USB port again, it is seen by them, and the *Mount devices* window shows up like it has detected some device to mount - still, Kingston isn't visible there.

I'm currently out of ideas because everything I've tried has failed, and when I search for solutions I can only find ones similar to what I've already tried - and failed at.

Please note that I'm not after the data I just want the device to work again.

Comment: Can you try to format your usb stick with this tool on Windows ? https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/ .By the way, i am not sure it will work, because if WinXP cannot see the drive i think this tool won't see it either...

Comment: Take device in your right hand, hold it over the round container next to your desk.  Let go.  Then go to Least Objectionable Purchase and spend $9.95 on a new one.

Comment: Thanks.No program in mini windows works because it can't see the usb so I'd like to try the Windows utilities too but unfortunately I have this problem with not only this usb drive but all of them except 2gb mp3 player which is too small to fit Windows iso file on so I can't reinstall Windows 8.1 enterprise evaluation on my only one of all hard drive which still works.I don't know why 8.1 says something like Boot something missing or corrupt.I'd go to recovery options but F8 or F8+Shift doesn't work.Maybe if I could fix that I'd get my storage devices working...

Comment: I thought about giving up a few times but I calculated that for twice the pendrive's cost I could have a much faster 1tb hard drive for about $30.Also I would like to be able to fix my storage problems Myself in the future so I won't have to fuss about with some technician and pay him more for the repair than the storage device is worth.

Comment: But are you saying I can't repair it?

Comment: A USB stick can not be economically repaired.  A company like **DriveSaver** can recover almost anything, but it cost hundreds of dollars.  If you knew how to use a soldering iron you might be to unsolder the actual memory chip and place it on another of the same make and model and there is at least a remote chance it might work.

Comment: @cybernard I don't know why the drive became RAW and after that stopped being seen as a mountable device because I haven't damaged it physically unless there was some sort of electricity harm and I don't know how software could have done this especially because it was optimized for "Quick Removal" in Windows' settings.So it is physically damaged?How?

Comment: I don't know how old your stick is, but this could be relevant.  Each sector on the stick can handle so many writes after that the sector is no longer usable.  If this happens to any of sectors used internally for the file system the stick is dead.  If this happens to sector 0 the device is lost.  If you need data recovery try ** http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download**

Comment: @cybernard it is about a year old almost unused.I want to give it to warranty but I don't know if I will get it since I don't have the receipt or any proof that I bought it in the local store except that the seller *might* want to remember that I actually bought it.I also have a 16gb μSD card (which I bought there too) also without receipt but with the μSd to SD adapter and paper back it came with.Please tell me will I get a warranty?

Comment: but anyway the usb can't be used up already because I almost haven't used it.So what is the answer?

Comment: Without knowing what model it is or who you bought it from, it is impossible to even guess if you get warranty replacement.  ** http://www.kingston.com/us/company/warranty#duration ** You can also check the manufactures warranty which might still be valid.   Some stores keep their own records, easily accessible via computer so they know how to target you with ads.  If your really nice, and access for an exchange the chances of success improve.

Comment: @cybernard http://www.amazon.com/Kingston-DataTraveler-Generation-DT100G2-16GBZ/dp/B0044XTJ1K/ref=cm_cr_pr_pb_t kingston syas I have 5yr warranty but please tell me what can I do if I will have to prove I bought it or when I bought it

Comment: If kingston says you have a warranty you are covered!! It is a kingston memory stick it has a kingston serial number on it.  Kingston does not care where you bought it, just that it is a kingston part.  **You may have to mail it to them fill out an RMA on there website.**  **The rma form does not even ask where you bought it from.**

Comment: That's what it says on the link you posted.I haven't told them anything but I'll try anyway.Thank you so much